# Re-writing Dynamic URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I'd like to remove the ".php" at the end of all webpages
AND
rewrite my dynamic urls for the section "example.com/archive?url=..."

**What I got so far:**

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This part works fine but now I also want to rewrite my dynamic urls for the following section of the website.

**Old url:** example.com/archive?url=test-article

**New url:** example.com/archive/test-article

```
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ archive?url=$1
```

This part doesn't work. What am I missing here?

It's used for an addon domain so maybe this has something to do with the problem?

**EDIT 1:**

I put some garbage in my .htaccess file and it generates an error so I know for sure it's reading the file.

**EDIT 2:**

I disabled multiviews as proposed below but getting an internal server error now.
This is the error log:

[Tue May 20 13:12:12 2014] [error] [client (ip)] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace

**Edit 3: I found the solution**

I solved the problem by changing the last rule into:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)$ archive?url=$1
```

Comment: Try removing the caret in `^archive/`, and if that works, try using `^/archive/` instead

Comment: How could `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html` work fine if you're trying to remove the "php" from the end of all webpages?

Comment: @Joh Lin: I don't know but it works. When the actual file is example.com/archive/2014.php then it loads the correct page when I link to example/archive/2014

Comment: I edited my code. I now disabled Multiviews but getting the following error log: [Tue May 20 13:12:12 2014] [error] [client (ip)] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have options `MultiViews` enabled.

You can disable that using:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

With `MultiViews` disabled it will not not serve `/file.php` when you request `/file`.

**EDIT:** As per your revised question you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)$ archive?url=$1
```

Comment: The message I got with Multiviews enabled:
"The requested URL /archief/test-article was not found on this server.

I then disabled Multiviews as you proposed but now I got the following message:
"Internal Server Error: the server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: Can you check your Apache error log to see what is causing 500?

Comment: This is the error log:
[Tue May 20 13:12:12 2014] [error] [client (ip)] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: That means you have some rule that is looping. Can you post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: I added the complete .htaccess file above.

Comment: I solved it by changing the last rule.
`RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)$ archive?url=$1`
Anyway thanks with the help with Multiviews!

Comment: Oh ok `/news/` wasn't in the original question. I edited answer now with your suggested rule change so that you can close this Q&A by marking it as accepted.

Comment: I have a new problem with my htaccess file. Could you please take a look at my new question too? It would help me a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956478/htaccess-file-replace-spaces-with-hypen-link-to-new-url

Comment: OK due let me take a look.