# htaccess file: replace spaces with hypen + link to new url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to replace any space in my URLs with a hypen

This is my complete htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ news?title=$1
```

The problem is that my title often contains spaces so it returns this url:

```
example.com/archive/this%20is%20a%20test
```

Url that I'd like to create: example.com/archive/this-is-a-test

I read that I could include a "\" to remove any spaces, but my attempts didn't work...

A related question: how do I link to this new url from another webpage? I cannot use the following php cause that would just return the url with the "%20" symbols:

```
<a class="readmore" href="/archive/<?php echo $row['title'];?>
```

Comment: spaces in urls should be a `+` anyways, not a `%20`.

Comment: When you load `example.com/archive/this-is-a-test`, does it load the page correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove spaces from start or after with + 
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s+]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

# remove spaces from end or before with + 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s+]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

# replace spaces by - in betweenwith +
RewriteRule ^([^\s+]*)(?:\s|+)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]
```